# window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать условие определения ссылки браузера, где присутствует определенный текст, вот что я написал, но неправильно:

```
if($('window.location[href*="emkosti"]').length) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myHref = window.location.href;
if (myHref.search('word') != -1){
твой код
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 1):

Зачем лезть в язык, не разобравшись в основах, а писать что-то **очень** странное?

```js
// window.location - объект с информацией о URI страницы
// indexOf - функция поиска подстроки, возвращает -1, если не найдено вхождение

if(window.location.indexOf('emkosti') !== -1){ // Если в пути страницы есть кусок 'emkosti' (т.е. вернулось НЕ -1)
  // Just do it
}
```